# Checking if $_POST is empty and return 1 message

Tags: php

I have a foreach loop to check if there is any empty post but i get 3x "empty" i only want to return 1 message if any post data is empty
I have this PHP code.

```
if (isset($_POST["registreer"]))
    {
        unset($_POST["registreer"]);

        foreach ($_POST as $input => $value)
        {
            if (empty($_POST[$input]))
            {
                echo "empty";
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: use `break;` to force coming out of the `foreach`, and display 1 `leeg`

Comment: Do you want to return 1 for each empty fields ?

Comment: echo '<pre>'; var_dump($_POST); echo '</pre>'; try it and share output and please describe clearly what question exactly is.

Comment: @AdilAbbasi Seems clear to me. The problem is that when there are 3 empty fields, it prints `empty` 3 times, he wants it to print it only 1 time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You won't need `foreach`, instead you can use [`in_array()`](http://www.php.net/in_array)

```
if (in_array("", $_POST)) {
   echo 'Whatever';
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `break` to end the loop after printing the message.

```
    foreach ($_POST as $input => $value)
    {
        if (empty($value))
        {
            echo "empty";
            break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: haha thanks, dindt know it was so easy. i was strugling with this for like 30 mins.

Comment: You need to learn the language. `break` is in PHP, C, Javascript and many other languages. It's also in `Perl`, except it's called `last`.

Answer (score 0):

The below will add the empty $_POST arrays to the $emp array and print them after the loop. You didn't say if you want to know which ones are empty, but hopefully it helps.

```
if (isset($_POST["registreer"]))
{
    unset($_POST["registreer"]);

    foreach ($_POST as $input => $value)
    {
        if (empty($_POST[$input]))
        {
            $emp[$input] = "leeg";

        } 
    }

    print_r($emp);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try This

```
if (isset($_POST["registreer"]))
    {
        unset($_POST["registreer"]);
        $flag =0;
        foreach ($_POST as $input => $value)
        {
            if (empty($_POST[$input]))
            {
                $flag = 1;
            }
        }
        if( $flag==1){
            echo "leeg";
         }
    }
```

This is return only one time "leeg" when post is empty

Comment: Why keep looping after you've found an empty element?

Comment: And you should use `true/false` for boolean data.

Answer (score 0):

Try it like this, If you want to display message only once, wither empty field is one or more.

```
$errorSent = 0;

if (isset($_POST["registreer"]))
{
    unset($_POST["registreer"]);

    foreach ($_POST as $input => $value)
    {
        if (empty($_POST[$input]))
        {
            if ($errorSent == 0)
            {
                echo "empty";
            }
            $errorSent = 1
        }
    }
}
```